# AngularJS ng-show is true but display:none remains

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

I have two buttons on a page that do basically the same thing. Button 1 retrieves a string and outputs it to a div. Button 2 retrieves the same string and outputs it to the same div, but it also retrieves a status code. Only 1 button can be pushed per page reload. Here is a pared-down version of my controller:

```
angular.module('myModule', []).controller('myController', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
  self = this;
  this.loaded = false;
  this.msg = '';

  this.getMessage = new Object(blah...);
  this.getMessage.success = function(data) {
    self.loaded = true;
    self.msg = data.msg;
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      self;
    });
  };

  this.getStatus = new Object(blah...);
  this.getStatus.success = function() {
    self.getMessage();
  };

  this.button1.click(function() {
    $.ajax(self.getMessage);
  });

  this.button2.click(function() {
    $.ajax(self.getStatus);
  });
}]);
```

I am using jQuery for the AJAX calls because I am migrating from jQuery to Angular, and am working from the front to the back to get all jQuery weeded out.  So far my page looks something like this:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- js/css inclusions -->
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller='myController as ctrl'>
    <div ng-show='ctrl.loaded' ng-bind='ctrl.msg'></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

On page load, my div looks like this:

```
<div class='ng-hide'
 ng-show='ctrl.loaded'
 ng-bind='ctrl.msg'
 style='display: none'></div>
```

When button 1 is clicked, my div turns into:

```
<div class=''
 ng-show='ctrl.loaded'
 ng-bind='ctrl.msg'
 style=''>Message Here.</div>
```

When button 2 is clicked, my div turns into:

```
<div class=''
 ng-show='ctrl.loaded'
 ng-bind='ctrl.msg'
 style='display: none'>Message Here.</div>
```

This div is not styled by me, just the default CSS from Angular for showing/hiding things. My question is: am I doing something wrong? Is there some sort of scoping issue that I'm not seeing? Something else that I'm not doing correctly (the Angular way)?

**Edit**: Injected `$scope` service into my controller, but still same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the HTTP calls are being made with jQuery instead of using the Angular `$http` service, Angular doesn't know that your `loaded` parameter is changing, and therefore doesn't update the view.

Wrap the code inside the success callbacks in a `$scope.$apply` block like below, so that Angular knows it needs to update the view scope when you've made your changes to the params. You'll also need to inject the `$scope` service into your controller.

```
this.getMessage.success = function(data) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        self.loaded = true;
        self.msg = data.msg
    });
};
```

Also, you should be using the `$scope` service to inject params into your view - that's what it's there for.

Comment: Is your edited code in your question what you've currently got in your controller? If so, give it a go with the code I provided (i.e.: move the parameter setting into the `$apply` block).

Comment: I moved the parameter settings into the `$apply` block, but still the same results... button 1 shows the message, but button 2 just won't allow the `display: none` to be removed.

Comment: Ok. It may be that the inner workings of Angular require parameters to be set on the `$scope` service instead of the controller itself, in order to form bindings between the view and controller. e.g.: `$scope.loaded` instead of `this.loaded`. Use it in your view as simply `loaded` - you don't need the `$scope` prefix (`ng-show="loaded"`).

Comment: Converting `this.loaded` to `$scope.loaded` and using `ng-show="loaded"` still gives the same results. :/

Comment: Can you make demonstrate this in a jsfiddle so I can have a play around?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9pjvkcav/2/  I put everything in the fiddle, but I've had no success getting the ng-app to load. Feel free to take a look. I'm still continuing to look up other solutions...

Comment: I've updated the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/9pjvkcav/3/. Once I'd got the app running, the primary problem was that the button handlers weren't been called. You had `ng-click="ctrl.button1"` not `ng-click="ctrl.button1()"`. Additionally, I used a `setTimeout` to simulate the jQuery AJAX call, and set properties on the `$scope` object rather than the controller and moved statements into the `$scope.$apply` block both as previously mentioned. Seems to be working.

Comment: Turns out a completely unrelated javascript file had some completely random jQuery that was hiding the div I needed. Great hint with the $scope.$apply though; very useful for converting from jQuery.